# How do I fix this unknown column error in sql query

Tags: sql, magento

I "think" I see the issue, but have not idea how to fix it

Got some great/quick help getting my query straighten out, but now I'm getting this error:
**Unknown column 'caet.entity_id' in 'where clause'**

The error appears in the third select statement. I want to say>> select the value where the **caev**.entity_id field matches the **caet**.entity_id.  I have checked, the spelling is correct and these fields are in both tables.

Should this work, do I need another join?

```
select c.*, 
(
select caet.value 
from customer_address_entity_text caet 
where cae.entity_id = caet.value_id 
and caet.attribute_id = 23
) as test,
(
select caev.value 
from customer_address_entity_varchar caev 
where caet.entity_id = caev.entity_id 
and caev.attribute_id = 23
) as two
from customer_entity c
join customer_address_entity cae on c.`entity_id` = cae.`parent_id`
where store_id = 15
```

The query below shows the inner join that I tried, but still get an error:

```
select c.*, 
(
select caet.value 
from customer_address_entity_text caet 
where cae.entity_id = caet.value_id 
and caet.attribute_id = 23
) as test,
(
select caev.value 
from customer_address_entity_varchar caev 
where caet.entity_id = caev.entity_id
and caev.attribute_id = 23
) as two
from customer_entity c
join customer_address_entity cae on c.`entity_id` = cae.`parent_id`
INNER JOIN customer_address_entity_text CAET ON CAET.id = CAEV.id 
where store_id = 8
```

Comment: `where cae.entity_id = caet.value_id `. There's no T

Comment: I am sorry I did say second select statement, I meant the third select caev.value 
from customer_address_entity_varchar caev 
where caet.entity_id = caev.entity_id

Comment: Just join the two on the ID. `INNER JOIN customer_address_entity_text CAET ON CAET.id = CAEV.id`?

Comment: No, I posted this, because it is separate from that one that was answered.

Answer (score 0):

CAEV is not in the outer context. So problem is "CAET.id = CAEV.id". You should join all tables in outer context and select in inner contexts. But inner join will not work. Use OUTER join. Maybe you may use below:

```sql
SELECT     c.*, caet.value AS test, caev.value AS two
FROM         customer_entity AS c INNER JOIN
                  customer_address_entity AS cae ON c.entity_id = cae.parent_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  customer_address_entity_text AS caet ON cae.entity_id = caet.value_id AND caet.attribute_id = 23 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  customer_address_entity_varchar AS caev ON cae.entity_id = caev.entity_id AND caev.attribute_id = 23
WHERE     (store_id = 15)
```